# Regression with vote data (yes/no/abstain) as dependent variable: Is there a specific model for this?

Tags: regression, multinomial-distribution

Assume I have data on multiple people, voting. They can either vote yes or no or abstain.

I would be curious how some predictors define the probability of the voters to vote yes.

I am insecure with the right model choice.

Just omitting people who abstain allows to choose between linear probability model ( I won't prefer), probit and logit. However, this would throw away useful data.

I could use a Heckman probit/logit or any other two-step, assuming that the choice of abstain is before the choice between yes and no. However, this would impose a somewhat arbitrary assumption. I am also not very happy with that, as very few people abstain in each decision.

Lastly, one could use multinominal logit/probit, which seem like a natural choice. However, it makes me wonder, whether to abstain is really the same option for the individual voter, as to vote either yes or no. Abstain is not a disjunct alternative, as is yes to no and vice versa.

Is there any third type of model, that is made for this specific type of problem?

I know, in some way, one could also just impute the overall result (either yes or no) to those people abstaining, because in the end, their vote expresses, that they follow the majority, but I somehow doubt, that this would be a usual way statistical educated people work.

Comment: Don't impute values to the abstain, because unless I misunderstood the question people chose to abstain. You shouldn't impute values to non-missing values.

I would use multinomial logisitc regression and be open about any limitations you think your approach has. Why couldn't you just have the abstain be your baseline category? Then you could address your question of how the dependent variable(s) changed the outcome in relation to eh baseline category.

Comment: Thank you. Well I want a model, that explains the voting (yes,no, choose not to vote) in my experiment. So I have no reference category, as vote is the depended variable, right?

Comment: There is more than one type of multinomial logistic regression. Since your data is in between interval and ordinal I would probably use a baseline category logit model. Which as the name implies will have a baseline ( or reference) category. Here is a link with a pretty quick intro https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/173 and here is a more thorough version http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c6.pdf

Comment: @RobertMontgomery Yes, your answer makes perfectly sense. Not all right hand i.e. independent variables are just ordinal, there are some interval, yes.